# Laravel: disallow direct access to Post method by users

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-exceptions

I have a website which is developed in Laravel.

Problem:

I have a route method (POST)

```
Route::post('/profile/edit/save', 'ProfileController@save');
```

if I enter this url "mywebsite.com/profile/edit/save" I get an error
     [image]
    Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

my .env file:

```
 APP_NAME=Laravel
 APP_ENV=production
 APP_DEBUG=false
 APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
 APP_URL=http://localhost
```

I get this error while running this code on my server,in Localhost I don't get any errors.

I have cleared the cache but it's not working

How can i solve this Problem?

Comment: If you want to access through the browser, you need to declare the route with GET method instead POST.

Comment: Maybe you have not understood my problem.
if a user or a hacker on my website sees the source code of the form and may be he wants to see the url where the data will be posted, when he will type this url in the browser he will receive this page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9Fl8.png

Comment: Check this solution: https://laravel.io/forum/10-14-2014-stack-trace-for-error-methodnotallowedhttpexception

Comment: thanks for your reply i found another solution you can see my answer

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it by adding this in app\Exceptions\handler.php

```
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
        {   

             if($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException){
                 return redirect('/');
             }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access to post url like you tried above 
You can only access by submitting form like this...

```
<form action="route('post_insert')" method="post">
  {{csrf_field()}}
   <input type="text" />
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

your route must include this name...

```
Route::post('/profile/save', 'ProfileController@save')->name('post_insert');
```

Comment: and you dont have 'route name' in your route in web.php
please insert  route name

Comment: see the link : https://gist.github.com/abdes-zakari/db42f618d16571c7aa74eb5284a6384f

Comment: <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-prd" id="js-save-profile">SAVE</button>

what the js code here???